# Use an object file which is using a kernel function removed with newer kernels on newer kernels?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

First off, I have a very superficial knowledge about C so I have no idea about what to do about this problem I'm having.

I need to build an object file which was compiled on kernel 4.4 into a kernel module.
The function `__memzero` that this object file uses was removed with kernel 4.16.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/arm/include/asm/string.h

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/arch/arm/include/asm/string.h

I need to use it on newer kernels.

Would it even be possible make this object file work on newer kernels by doing anything at all? Like, somehow modify the object file to use an existing function like `__memset32`?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be a kernel module and not just a userspace function?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to add support for a proprietary switch driver, it has to be a kernel module.
Edit: Or could be built into kernel, same result for me.

Comment: FYI, C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, the C++ language allows function and operating overloading, C doesn't.  C++ has exception handling, like `try` and `catch` whereas C doesn't.  You can name a variable `class` or `private` in C, but not in C++.  C++ has inheritance, but C++ doesn't.  So, are you mixing the languages?  Please update your tags as appropriate.

Comment: I've removed mentions to the C++ language, thank you.

Comment: "Would it even be possible make this object file work on newer kernels by doing anything at all? Like, somehow modify the object file to use an existing function like __memset32?" - Yes, modifying a code in the object file could be a way to go. But without reasonable knowledge in assembler and C language, this could be very difficult way. Not, that aside from undefined function, there could be other problems with your object file when you port it to the new kernel. E.g. size of some structures you use could change. Normally, an object file created for one version could not be used with other.

Comment: This comment is good enough for an answer. Can you put it there so I can close this question?